# Receiving token by client after google authorization

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, nestjs, google-oauth

I am building a fullstack application on React+TS and Nest. In Nest I have a working logic for redirecting to authorization via google.

```
@Get('google')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('google'))
  async googleLogin() {
    // This handler will automatically redirect the user to the VK page for authentication
  }

  @Get('google/callback')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('google'))
  async googleAuthRedirect(@Req() req, @Res() res) {
    return this.authService.googleLogin(req);
    // returns {access_token, refresh_token{enter image description here
  }
```

When I fetch localhost:3333/auth/google.
it redirects me to the authorization page, and after authorization to localhost:3333/auth/google/callback, which returns the token object: {access_token:"", refresh_token:""}

[/auth/google/callback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYe9W.png)

I am facing a problem, how to get this token object from the client side(React)? I can't seem to just use axios.get(/auth/google/callback) because each callback is different.

So, my goal is to make such logic:

1. client clicks on the button
2. it redirects him to (server)/auth/google
3. user completes the form
4. tokens from auth/google/callback are saved in localstorage via React
5. redirect to localhost:5173/poll

If it was a regular get route, I would just access it via axios.get(auth/google/callback). But apparently it throws an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that we can write data to cookies from the backend as well. So, I changed my controller function

```
async googleAuthRedirect(@Req() req, @Res() res) {
  const authTokens = await this.authService.getVkTokens(req);
  res.cookie('refresh_token', authTokens.refreshToken);
  res.cookie('access_token', authTokens.accessToken);
}
```

Used [cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) here